# datatable how to create expandable child

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable

Using Datatable jquery. I can't seem to find an example where you can expand a child's child and show its content. If anyone could show me a simple example that would be great.

The image below shows two plus signs, once clicked it should expand the child's content.

[image]

Comment: Just a suggestion: At some point, DataTables becomes the wrong tool for the job (for example, maybe for expanding a child's child). I would consider making the child a collapsible tree. There are various [pre-built ones](https://www.jqueryscript.net/blog/Best-Tree-View-Plugins-jQuery.html) you can take a look at, as a starting point.

Comment: @andrewJames . Yeah ok thanks for the recommendation! I got this new project I am working on and everywhere is just datatables and jquery. Coming from React Land i can easily do this with that. But this project is just jquery and datatables,  i though i could do this with just datatables. I saw other examples with just jquery so i might resort to that. Anyways thanks a bunch.